# Input fields inside of dijit.dialog

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have foloowing form:
(part of the code here)

```
<form id="form1" ...>

   <input name="field1" value="1" type="hidden" />
   <input name="field2" value="2" type="hidden" />

   <div dojo-data-type="dijit.dialog">
      <input name="field3" value="3" type="hidden" />
      <button id="btn" dojo-data-type="dijit.button" onClick="submitForm('form1')">
   </div>

</form>
```

if I click the button "btn", i have in POST-collection ONLY fields "field1" and "field2", but not "field3". Waht's the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you walk the DOM's form children, the dialog elements will be absent; they end up down the bottom of the DOM. Inspect the page elements to verify.

Comment: What is the best way to POST these fields as content of my form?

Comment: That depends on what `submitForm` does. If this were a page submit (as opposed to an AJAX submit) you could move the DOM elements back into the form prior to POSTing the data.